Wifi Speed is 33 Mbps while in Windows it was 100 Mbps
Recently, I've upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04 LTS. Here is the deal, when I was in 22.04, I had the same problem. However, whenever I opened the terminal and ran the following bash file:
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sleep 1
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci

It was working just fine whenever I run this code. Now I have 24.04.1 LTS and this no longer works.
I tried many possible solutions.

Deactivate wi-fi powersave from
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DISABLE

Kernel update

Changing bandwidth from 2.4 to 5 GHz and other way around.

Changing DNS server (I know it was not related) ```


 I saw sth about **11n_disable** settings but in my /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf file the content is:

    remove iwlwifi \
    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

Maybe the problem might be related. And the following is the output of the **modinfo iwlfwifi**:

    ❯ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 11n
    parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
    
    ❯ modinfo iwlwifi           
    filename:       /lib/modules/6.10.5-061005-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko.zst
    license:        GPL
    description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
    firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-77.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-77.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-77.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-77.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-77.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf4-a0.pnvm
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0.pnvm
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
    firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0.pnvm
    firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-b0-mr-a0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf4-a0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-b0-hr-b0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-mr-a0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf4-a0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ma-a0-hr-b0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-89.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-gl-c0-fm-c0.pnvm
    firmware:       iwlwifi-gl-c0-fm-c0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-gl-b0-fm-b0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm4-b0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-b0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-gf4-a0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-gf-a0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-bz-a0-hr-b0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc2f-a0-wh-a0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc2f-a0-fm-c0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc2-a0-wh-a0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc2-a0-fm-c0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc-a0-wh-a0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc-a0-gf4-a0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc-a0-gf-a0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc-a0-hr-b0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc-a0-hr-b0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc-a0-fm-c0-90.ucode
    firmware:       iwlwifi-sc-a0-fm-b0-90.ucode
    srcversion:     D1D3E7042D796751A9DBC0F
    parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
    parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
    parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
    parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
    parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
    parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
    parm:           enable_ini:0:disable, 1-15:FW_DBG_PRESET Values, 16:enabled without preset value defined,Debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 16) (uint)
    parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
    parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
    parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
    parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
    parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
    parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
    parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
    parm:           disable_11be:Disable EHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)


Changing kernel from what to what?

@DavidDE 6.5 to 6.8 but that has no use

A successful upgrade should have given you kernel 6.8, the default with Ubuntu 24.04 Also the kernel number should be expressed in full as many have found for example the 6.8.39 does not work for them but 6.8.40 does

Sure, I know that but I do not think my main issue is related to kernel version. Do we really have to this specific on this matter? Can you have any idea why I have this problem?

Yes you always need to state the full and correct version info as well as the complete kernel info, You expect a working answer and do not want to give specific info?

OK. I'm currently working on 6.8.41 while I was 6.5.0
